# What to try next if linear stability analysis fails? determining the equilibrium points of an ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Say I have and ODE, and I want to classify its equilibrium points.

First one usually tries linear stability analysis. However if the Jacobian has at least one zero as an eigenvalue what are the next methods that one could try to use?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Lyapunov's_second_method_for_stability

Comment: There's also center manifold theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_manifold